# OAuth2 Authentication in Django Rest Swagger

Tags: django, python-2.7, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework, django-rest-swagger

I am Using Django Rest Swagger with Python 2.7 and Django 1.11 . I am trying to use OAuth authentication with Swagger. I have included this in my settings.py

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
"basePath": "/v2",
'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
    'api_authorization': {
        "type": "oauth2",
        "in": "header",
        "tokenUrl": "http://localhost:8000/o/token/",
        "authorizationUrl": "http://localhost:8000/o/authorize/",
        "name": "Authorization",
        "state": "random_state_string",
        "flow": "accessCode",
        "scopes": {
            "read": "Reading scope",
            "write": "Writing scope"
        }

    }
}
```

}

When I click the Authorize button in Swagger it doesn't ask for client-id, instead it shows following screen.

[image]

How to make the Django Rest Swagger wotk with OAuth Authentication?

Answer (score -1):

I think the general answer is that you must provide an oath service from your Django app.  Django Rest Swagger is not providing the OAUTH service.  You'd have to add that as a separate Django app.

Searching the web for "django oauth2 PROVIDER" pulls up some options.

For example:

https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/